Sharing Notebooks on Vertex AI Workbench
We are trying to share notebooks with my colleagues without commiting to git. I understand that Colab Enterprise can do this easily as you can just share a link. Wondering if it was possible to do something similar with Workbench.
We are using terragrunt files to spin up our Workbench instances. So wondering if we can possibly attach a GCS bucket which contain all our notebooks for example?
Happy for other solutions.


You can create Workbench instance in Service Account mode and use "Shareable Link"


2. Other option is to mount a GCS bucket and use GCSfuse to mount the folder and write Notebook files there. Example here.

If we use GCSfuse, is there a way to mount it to our local laptop too. Hoping to recreate the functionality of google drive somehow.

Yes, basically the source of truth with GCSfuse is your GCS bucket. So if you monunt it locally in laptop and/or Cloud instance you would be modifying the file in GCS bucket.
